# create menubar in jsf 2.0

Tags: css, html, jsf

I want to make Menu bar in JSF 2.0 without using any component suite like ICEfaces, PrimeFaces. 
Is it possible? Or I just have to use all HTML and CSS to create it?

Comment: JSF components generates HTML/CSS code. If you don't want to use JSF components, regardless of component library, you obviously have to write/generate all that HTML/CSS code yourself.

Comment: Thank u BalusC for ur response.
i regularly check ur blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use a client side library like jQuery. For example see [here](http://view.jqueryui.com/menubar/demos/menubar/default.html)